# Facebook graph API -- what do "x" and "y" on tags mean? Is the documentation outdated?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an app that needs to deal with users' Facebook photos. At the moment, I'm playing around in the Graph API Explorer to make sure that I understand how everything works. I'm a little confused by [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/photo) which appears to be out of date.

The documentation states that tags are under an `object[]` called `name_tags`. At least in the Graph API Explorer, there is nothing called `name_tags` -- but there is something called `tags`. `tags` has different properties than the ones listed in the documentation for `name_tags`; it looks like this:

```
"tags": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "10202658245962264",
            "name": "Patrick Collins",
            "created_time": "2014-06-29T22:00:36+0000",
            "x": 33.333335876465,
            "y": 58.911109924316
          }
        ], 
       .....
}
```

What do `x` and `y` mean here? They appear to be percentage offsets from the upper left hand corner -- is that correct? Are they located in the center of the bounding box that contains the tagged user's face, or the top left?

My goal is to train 3rd party facial recognition software on users' Facebook photos, so I want to be able to test whether the software and Facebook agree on what the person looks like. The facial recognition software finds a bounding box containing the face, so I want to know if I need to be testing if `x` and `y` are inside that box, or if they're near some corner.

Additionally, why does the documentation talk about `name_tags` and `offset`, neither of which are contained in the API's response on the `/{photo-id}` endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make just a comment rather than an answer, but my reputation score here is below 50, so I can't. :'(

I'm not sure what they are, but just based on the values, they look like geo locations.
Aren't they Longitude and Latitude?
(like here : http://goo.gl/jEaABH )

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that x and y represents percentages. If you ask API for height and width of the photo you can easily do width TIMESx=x_center_of_rectangle_around_face and height TIMESy=y_center_of_rectangle_around_face.